# Chained transactional api calls spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactional

I have a problem where I am not getting my transactions are commited

My Service class is @Transactional annotated

```
@Transactional
class MyService{
   public void find();
   public void return(); //Return will only happen if find is updated in DB
   public void cancel(){
          find();
          return();
   }
}
```

My class have 3 api they internally call the respective Dao, and Dao as are not annotated as Transactional.

Now if I call cancel, I will call first find and then the return(). But return() need the find() need to be updated the DB with FIND status.

But since all are happening on the same transaction untill the cancel is returned the transactions are not commited. Can someone help me to understand this situation and fix it.

I dunno how can I use Propagation in this situation.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: They use the same transaction that means the changes made in the transaction are visible for all the selects called from the transaction

Comment: In the same transaction itself, Even though the find() updated the DB, while I am checking from return() i am not able to see the DB as updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exerpt from Spring Transcation documentation ([Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html))

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional.

The calls to find() and return() inside cancel() method are not transactional. If you want it to be transactional you can do something like `applicationContext.getBean(this.getClass());` and call your methods.

Comment: IS there anyway using the propagation to initiate a new transaction for each calls from the target object itself.

Comment: if you call find() like this applicationContext.getBean(this.getClass()).find() spring will use the current transaction. you can add annotation REQUIRES_NEW on find() declaration and Spring will initiate a new transaction on each call.

Comment: Is that safe to call on the Bean inside from the same bean. Could you please tell me if that going to make any indirect impact to my system. Since I never did something like that And the project is a critical and should be consistent I am worried about accessing the same bean inside the bean itself

Comment: Things are working perfectly, thanks for helping me on this. Accepting this as a answer, Let me know the indirect impacts(if any) of using a bean inside the same bean using the applicationContext

Comment: In fact when you have to do this kind of 'trick', it demonstrate a problem in your architecture. Maybe your service layer should be re organize or you should add an orchestration layer, or be aware of some useless layer doing nothing more than just calling another layer. However in term of performance it's not a problem.